# What do "derivation" and "build" mean?

Tags: nixos, terminology

The manpage of nix-build says:

> The  nix-build  command builds the derivations described by the Nix expressions in paths.

What does "derivation" mean? Is it the same as "package"? More specifically, binary package?

Does "build" mean compilation from source code to binary?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of https://nixos.org/manual/nix/unstable/glossary.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, you can think of "derivation" as a recipe to build (=compile) a package. This derivation specifies how to fetch the source, which dependencies must be used to build the package, what command to run to build it, and how to install the built files. This is not specific to binary packages, you can create a derivation outputting any sort of file (binary, images, translation files, scripts…).